# Calculating orders of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let σ:=(134), τ:=(258796) be permutations in S9. Calculate the order of σ and τ3.

I have no idea how to do this at all. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: The order of a permutation $\pi$ is the least $k$ such that $\pi^k$ is the identity permutation. Take the integers from 1-9, apply $\sigma$ to them, and keep doing that until everything is back in its original order. Then do the same with $\tau$. You may figure out a shortcut yourself along the way.

Answer (score 3):

Sing along with me:

"Two goes to (skip two) seven, seven goes to (skip two) two, five goes to (skip two) nine, and nine goes to (skip two) five. Bring it on home! Eight goes to (skip two) six, and six goes to (skip two) eight."

Hopefully this little ditty convinces you that $\tau^3 = (2\ 7)(5\ 9)(8\ 6)$, which has order $2$, which makes sense since $\tau$ has order $6$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can *feel* it!